# Angular Momentum and Force

Tags: classical-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum

[image]

I'm stuck on number 5. The answers to the first 4 are correct, but I dont know how to set up number 5. Any idea that I would have would require me having some kind of time information, but thats not given. Any suggestions?

Comment: Our goal here is an answer conceptual questions as opposed to homework questions, so I would prefer omitting the picture and asking something like, "Suppose I have a small bit of mass stuck on the outside of a spinning hoop.  I know by intuition that the hoop is essentially 'trying to throw the mass off', but I don't know how to calculate this effect.  How would I find the force between the hoop and the mass?"

Comment: Our aim here is to learn new concepts or to ask conceptual questions. Not like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but I can make an educated guess. Firstly, I envisage a person sitting on the merry-go round with their body pointed tangentially to the circle, in which cases *no* force *in that direction* is required.

However, if the person is free to move radially (can slip inwards/outwards), then a force is required to counteract the centripetal force. In other words,

$$F_{holding} = F_{centripetal}$$

Consider the appropriate equation for centripetal force in terms of your known variables, and you can then plug in the values to get the answer.

(P.S. Don't look at my edit unless you want the answer, best you try yourself first!)

Comment: Question in English: what is the name of a radial force acting toward the center ? What is the name of the pseudo-force introduced in the rotating frame of reference ? Because you said "to counteract the centripetal force" ... I would say that the force  we are talking about is the centripetal force... (in French we make a distinction "centripeDe" and "centripeTe").

Comment: @Cedric: Yes, this is a slight problem of language. I'm considering the whole problem from the inertial frame of the ground. In this case, there is only a *centripetal* force. A force needs to be exerted by the person to counteract this, otherwise the person would fly off. Of course, you can also consider the problem from the rotating reference frame and talk about the *centrifugal* pseudo-force. Just complicates things though, in my view. (Oh, and in English *centripedal* is not a word - maybe a common mispelling of *centripetal*. Confusing, if you speak French, I admit!)

Comment: OK thanks for this clarification ! So centripetal and centrifugal.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Good to know the French terms too for when I meet other physicists.

Answer (score 1):

Think about these:

1. What is the shape of the path the person takes?
2. What force is needed to keep the person traveling along that path?